# Mapping a weak entity in M:M Relationship

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have a mapper function:

```
public void Mapper(List<Item> items, List<List> lists, List<ListItem> listItems)
    {
        using (var command = Context.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = @"SELECT ListItem.ListId, ListItem.ItemId, Item.ItemId AS ItemItemId, List.ListId AS ListListId 
                                        FROM Item INNER JOIN
                                        ListItem ON Item.ItemId = ListItem.ItemId INNER JOIN
                                        List ON ListItem.ListId = List.ListId";
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    int listid = (int)reader["ListId"];
                    int itemid = (int)reader["ItemId"];
                    int listlistid = (int)reader["ListId"];
                    int itemitemid = (int)reader["ItemItemId"];

                    foreach (var listitem in listItems)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in items)
                        {
                            if (item.ItemId == itemitemid && itemitemid == itemid)
                            {
                                listitem.Item = item;
                            }
                        }

                        foreach (var list in lists)
                        {
                            if (list.ListId == listlistid && listlistid == listid)
                            {
                                listitem.List = list;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My goal is that the 3 parameters of lists of entities, that I have got from my database, but I need to map the references between "List and Listitem" and "Item and ListItem".

My problem is that it always seem to map the references to the LAST Item and List in its tables, for an example, if I was my last list in its Table was "Fridge" and the last Item in its table was "Milk", all listitems will have a reference to those.

Can anyone help? And tell me if I need to provide more code in comments please. :)

EDIT: ListItem Implementation

```
public class ListItem
{
public virtual int Amount
{
    get;
    set;
}

public virtual int Volume
{
    get;
    set;
}

public virtual string Unit
{
    get;
    set;
}

public virtual List List
{
    get;
    set;
}

public virtual Item Item
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The reason why all elements from `listItems` end up having their `Item` assigned to the last element in `items` and their `List` assigned to the last element in `lists` is because every element in `listItems` (see `foreach`) is ultimately being assigned, **unconditionally**, for every `ListItem` in the database (see outer-most `while`).

To explain more simply, the code you have is the logical equivalent of this pseudo-code.

```
foreach (db_element in db)
{
    foreach (list_element in list)
    {
        list_element.property = ...;
    }
}
```

Assuming 3 elements in `db` and 5 elements in `list` there would be 15 assignments (3 x 5 = 15), instead of just 3 as you may have intended.

Instead, this is how you can implement a condition for matching the appropriate element from `list`

```
foreach (db_element in db)
{
    foreach (list_element in list)
    {
        if (list_element.ItemId == db_element.ItemId &&
            list_element.ListId == db_element.ListId)
        {
             list_element.property = ...;
        }
        else
        {
             // wrong one! skip.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an idea to fix my problem?

Comment: I need to understand why you need a listItems method argument.  If you're changing existing objects, you need to add some matching condition to find the right ones to update.  If you're able to add new ones, it can be done without this matching logic.

Comment: Your problem is not so much a coding problem as it is a requirement problem.

Comment: I have the listitems argument, because that already contains all ListItems properties except the references to List and Item.

Comment: So let's say there's 3.  How will you know which specific item and list to link them to?

Comment: ListItem is a weak entity in the Database, therefore it's PK's and FK's are ListId and ListId. Screenshot of dbo design: http://imgur.com/GuzMtpa

Comment: I understand what you're saying.  The difficulty is knowing that you're only giving me an object { Amount, Volume, Unit } and asking of me to tell you what Item it references.  It is impossible to know.  You've not given me any ID.  The information is now lost?

Comment: Ahh, Im starting to see I need the ListId and ItemId in the ListItem class aswell. Just worried about redundant data between ListItem.ListId and ListItem.List.ListId.

Comment: Yes, it is this very condition that you need to add to your code to make sure you set the properties for the correct listItem, and not all of them everytime.  Please remember to leave some votes for answers and comments you find useful.

Comment: And by condition, you mean ListId and ItemId, or am I misscorrected?

Comment: By condition, I mean finding the correct listItem to work with given the current row from the DB (matching on the compound key as you have it there).

Comment: Im don't understand what you mean by condition yet. can you give me an example?

Comment: I'll add to the answer then. The IF-statement is also called a condition.

Comment: what's the db_element? Why would you have both conditions in one `if`?

Comment: Because you're matching on a compound key. I think a good option for you is to try it first and once you've found that it works then dig deeper to understand why.  Please don't confuse the variable names in this pseudo-code with those from your code - they are unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I've changed your code for you so you can see exactly what I mean by adding the condition.

Look out for the lines where we're doing a `continue`.

```
public void Mapper(List<Item> items, List<List> lists, List<ListItem> listItems)
{
    using (var command = Context.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = @"SELECT ListItem.ListId, ListItem.ItemId, Item.ItemId AS ItemItemId, List.ListId AS ListListId 
                                    FROM Item INNER JOIN
                                    ListItem ON Item.ItemId = ListItem.ItemId INNER JOIN
                                    List ON ListItem.ListId = List.ListId";
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int listid = (int)reader["ListId"];
                int itemid = (int)reader["ItemId"];
                int listlistid = (int)reader["ListId"];
                int itemitemid = (int)reader["ItemItemId"];

                foreach (var listitem in listItems)
                {
                    // This is the condition you're missing.
                    if (listitem.ListId != listid &&
                        listitem.ItemId != itemid)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    foreach (var item in items)
                    {
                        if (item.ItemId == itemitemid && itemitemid == itemid)
                        {
                            listitem.Item = item;
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (var list in lists)
                    {
                        if (list.ListId == listlistid && listlistid == listid)
                        {
                            listitem.List = list;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what am I supposed to add instead of the continue?

Comment: continue is the code itself. The keyword tells the foreach enumerator to advance (skip) to the next element.